# Return all values of a table from SQL with a drop down as front end and using where clause and prepared statements in the back end

Tags: java, sql

So I have a front end where I give users the option to choose a value which is found in a SQL column or not choose anything. I have code which takes in this value and queries SQL using Prepared Statements. I can't figure out how to return all values if the user selects blank.

My front end code for a drop down list is as follows:

```
<form name="subinventory" action="subinventory.jsp" method="POST">
<select name="productname">
    <option>-1</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>X</option> 
</select>
     <b> Product Category </b>
<select name="productcategory">
    <option>IGNORE</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>X</option> 
</select>
      <b> Product Use </b>
<select name="productuse">
    <option>IGNORE</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>X</option> 
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

My back end is as follows

```
        String productname = (String)request.getParameter("productname");
        String producttype = (String)request.getParameter("producttype");
        String productuse = (String)request.getParameter("productuse");
        String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyNewDatabase";

        String USER = "root";
        String PASS = "user";
        Connection conn = null;


        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement() ;
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from Database WHERE Approved ='Approved' AND Product = '"  +productname+("'")+ "AND USES = '"  +  productuse+("'") ) ;
```

Comment: Just execute a different select and remove the constraints, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have understood from your question is,

> you want to retrieve data based on multiple conditions.

For that case, you can construct the basic query and then add the appropriate parameters based on conditions.

```
String query = "select * from Database WHERE Approved ='Approved'";
if(null != productname && !"".equals(productname)) {
      query += " AND Product = '"  +productname+"'";
}
if(null != productuse && !"".equals(productuse)) {
      query += " AND USES = '"  +productuse+"'";
}
```

like so ...

by the way what you are using is [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html). Not [Prepared Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: That is true. Thanks. I will check to see if it works and mark your answer as correct if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Use like in place of =
select * from Database WHERE Approved ='Approved' AND Product LIKE %'"  +productname+("'")+ "AND USES LIKE %'"  +  productuse+("'")